# Can I change a SQL Server table name in a way that is backwards compatible? E.g add a permanent alias?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, alias

I have a Sql Server 2008 database I inherited. A number of apps and SSIS packages work off that database. Not too long ago the scope of the database changed and a lot of new tables were added. As a result of this a lot of the table names (and even the database name itself) no longer make sense, resulting in a very confusing schema.

I could rename the tables straight away and change the apps and processes to use the new names but the chaos and downtime it would cause in the meantime would not be acceptable.

Is there a way I can add an alternate name for a table (like a permanent alias) that I could use to refer to either the new or old table name until all of my refactoring is complete?

Comment: Maybe creating views (implemented as simple selects) for this tables could be solution? The view could be treated as alias.

Comment: I vote leave it, or re-name and create views.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526068/sql-server-table-and-column-alias-for-legacy-applications

Answer (score 4):

Create a synonym first.

```
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.SensibleName FOR dbo.CrazyName;
```

Now find all the references to `CrazyName` in your codebase, and update them to reference `SensibleName` instead. Once you believe you have found them all, you can eventually run:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
  DROP SYNONYM dbo.SensibleName;
  EXEC sp_rename N'dbo.CrazyName', N'SensibleName', N'OBJECT';
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

If you need to make *column* names more sensible, you'll have to do so using a view, as synonyms only cover a subset of database-level objects.

[Some other info here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2071/make-your-sql-server-database-changes-backward-compatible-when-renaming-an-entity/?utm_source=AaronBertrand).

Answer (score 2):

You can rename it with `sp_rename` and then add synonym:

```
CREATE SYNONYM OldTableName FOR NewTableName
```